# Fluid mesh isn't showing in Mantaflow simulation

Tags: mesh, physics, fluid-simulation

The blue preview particles are showing, but whenever I tick the "Mesh" box under the physics properties on the domain, nothing happens. I've done multiple bakes with the box ticked, but it still previews as particles instead of a solid mesh. the mesh that is being used as an inflow (from geometry) source is planar, but the "is planar" box under settings > flow source is ticked.

[image: My simulation and settings]

Troubleshooting tips that I have tried that did not affect the outcome:

- adjusting the resolution divisions
- setting the surface emission of the flow mesh to a nonzero value
- Setting the fluid cache type to "All"
- closing and reopening the .blend file

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out that I had set my domain to display as bounds in its object properties. Duh

Comment: I did the same and couldn't figure my error out - thanks for that lifesaver :)